# Node.js : How to register services in Consul Agent from a JSON file

Tags: node.js, consul

I understand that services can be registered with a Consul agent from a JSON file, where services and other metadata can be defined through [command line](https://www.consul.io/commands/services/register).

But how do it through [Node.js consul client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example script which registers a service called 'test-service' to a local Consul client agent.

```js
import consul from 'consul';

const consulClient = new consul();

let serviceDefinition = {
    name: "test-service",
    tags: ['test', 'nonprod']
}

// Register the 'test-service' with the local agent
consulClient.agent.service.register(serviceDefinition, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Refer to https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/services and https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#register-service for a list of supported options when registering a service.

The only required field is `name`. All other fields are optional.